# Running a SQL SELECT statement against a MYSQL column of SET type

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a SQL SELECT statement against a column that is of type SET.  The table is called `myTable` and the columns in `myTable` are called `base_props` and `names`.  The `base_props` column is of type SET.  The values in `base_prop` are `vb`,`nt`, `cnt`,`poss` and `loc`.  So I would like to SELECT entries from the column 'name' where `base_props` have both the values, `vb` and `poss`.  The results I'm looking to get may have values other than just `vb` and `poss`.  So to be clear I would like to select all entries that have the values `vb` and `poss` regardless if they have other values as well.  I've tried the following SQL queries but I can't get the desired results.

```
SELECT name from myTable WHERE base_props = 'vb' AND base_props = 'poss'
```

That query returns an empty result set.  I've tried using `FIND_IN_SET()` and `IN()` but I couldn't get anywhere with that.  I've written SQL statements before but never had to deal with columns that are type SET.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To match the strings exactly, use `FIND_IN_SET` function. The order of the arguments trips some people up... first argument is the member (string) to search for, second argument is the set to be searched. You can also use the `LIKE` operator, but note that `base_props LIKE '%nt%'` will match both `'cnt'` as well as `'nt'`. You can use the `IN` operator, but that's equivalent to performing an equality test on the entire string returned for the SET col, the same as the `=` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can come up with is using the LIKE keyword:

```
SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE (base_props LIKE '%vb%' AND base_props LIKE '%poss%');
```

This will make sure both vb and cnt are in the base_props column. Of course you can use cnt, nt and loc in there, or any number of base_props values in the sql, just add more `AND` statements.

OR as a deleted answer by samitha pointed out, you can use FIND_IN_SET:

```
SELECT name from myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('vb', base_props) AND FIND_IN_SET('poss', base_props);
```

**Comment (by *spencer7593*):** "both of these work, but there is a slight difference. The LIKE operator will actually match any member that includes the search string anywhere in a term; the FIND_IN_SET function will only match an exact member. It's also possible to search for members in set by the order they appear in the SET definition, using the MySQL BITAND operator: for example, to match the 1st and 4th members of the set: WHERE base_props & 1 AND base_props & 8". So for example, if you have 'a' and 'aaa' in your set, then using the `LIKE "%a%"` method will also return rows containing 'aaa'.

**Conclusion:** use the `FIND_IN_SET` solution since it will work for all cases.

Comment: +1 Yes, both of these work, but there is a slight difference. The `LIKE` operator will actually match any member that includes the search string anywhere in a term; the `FIND_IN_SET` function will only match an exact member. It's also possible to search for members in set by the order they appear in the SET definition, using the MySQL BITAND operator: for example, to match the 1st and 4th members of the set: `WHERE base_props & 1 AND base_props & 8`.

Comment: Thats true @spencer7593, so the LIKE won't work if we have 2 values in the set like a and aaa, then we do a search for a, and aaa will also come up!, I'll add your comment to the answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, the `LIKE` operator works just fine. It just does something different than FIND_IN_SET. In the OP case, the SET contains both 'nt' and 'cnt' members. To use LIKE to match just 'nt' we could: `WHERE (base_props LIKE 'nt' OR base_props LIKE 'nt,%' OR base_props LIKE '%,nt' OR base_props LIKE '%,nt,%'`. (Check for the value as the only member, the first member in the set, the last member in the set, or in the middle of the set. (We could append a comma to the beginning and end of base_props, just search for `',nt,'`, but `FIND_IN_SET` would be more efficient than either of those.

Answer (score 0):

FIND_IN_SET return index, Try this

```
SELECT name from myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(base_props, 'vb') > 0 AND 
FIND_IN_SET(base_props, 'poss') > 0
```

Comment: I believe you've got the order of the FIND_IN_SET arguments reversed,; first argument is member to match, and the second argument is the set to be searched. The `FIND_IN_SET` functions will work just fine with the InnoDB storage engine. (It's possible there are some optimizations in the MyISAM engine, I don't know about that.)

Comment: @spencer7593, you are right,  FIND_IN_SET function will also working with InnoDB storage engine. i have updated answer